# Encoding wav to flac and streaming through node.js

Tags: node.js, streaming, flac

Am trying to create an application which will take data as raw audio wav format and output as FLAC.

Now, I need to stream the input and the output at the same time through node.

Can someone guide me on how can I work this out?

Thanks

Comment: can you reach the almighty site named google.com ? please search for tutorial there.

Comment: Well, I did.. but didn't find anything that'll encode a live stream of data..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no possibility to do so "live" via the Internet. You can't do so with FLAC format. Only AAC, MP3 an WAV are supported for live-streaming.
You can download the file on the client side and then the client using his or het apps is able to play it.